# How can I launch an application as administrator after a WiX MSI has completed?

Tags: windows-7, wix, windows-installer, wix3

How can I launch an application with administrator rights after I have completed an installation using a WiX-based [MSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Installer)?

I can launch the application just fine on Windows XP, but with Windows 7, it's an issue.

The application has a manifest embedded in it that says it should run as administrator and I've changed the impersonate attribute in the Custom Action to "no". I can't change the execute attribute to deferred, as this only works before the InstallFinalize action, and I need it after the user has clicked Finish in the MSI.

This is my custom action:

```
<CustomAction Id="LaunchApp" FileKey="App" ExeCommand="[Command Line Args]" Execute="immediate" Impersonate="no" Return="asyncNoWait" />
```

Comment: This is effectively a duplicate of [Executing a custom action that requires elevation after install](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2325459/executing-a-custom-action-that-requires-elevation-after-install) so look into WixShellExec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't use WixShellExec as I needed to pass in command line arguments if certain conditions were true. So I just created a custom action that launched the exe through cmd prompt. Hacky, but a viable workaround and it works without a hitch.

Comment: Huh, I hadn't used it so didn't realize WixShellExec didn't handle arguments. How odd! Well you can always create your own C++ DLL custom action which calls ShellExecute...